# Does Semantic Search also mean Semantic SEO?

Tags: seo, search-engines, search-results, terminology

I am doing a long essay on SEO and just wanted to be totally clear on the fact Semantic Search - the process of optimizing search engines to understand the query and display information accurately, can also be called Semantic SEO.

Dull question yes just need to be 110% sure.

Comment: I would think that semantic search describes the search engine methodology whereas semantic SEO describes the activities of a website owner. SEO is where a web site owner optimizes his sites content for better search performance. How search engines work, at least Google, is apply semantic analysis metrics to sites, pages, and search queries to make a proper match. Clear as mud?? Cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [Moz blog post](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6080550?hl=en) that addresses this quite well:

> ...there is a concise definition of semantic search provided by Tamas Doszkocs of [WebLib](http://weblib.com/):
>
> **"Semantic search is a search or a question or an action that produces meaningful results, even when the retrieved items contain none of the query terms, or the search involves no query text at all."**
>
> ...However, there's still not an agreed-upon term to describe the activities around achieving visibility in the semantic search results or optimizing for a semantic search engine.
>
> I've heard everything from "entity-based SEO" to "entity SEO" to "Search Entity Optimization" as descriptors for optimizing around entity-based results. I'd personally lean towards "semantic search optimization" or "semantic SEO," but I can guarantee one thing: It doesn't matter what you call it at the end of the day. Adjusting to the semantic search landscape will be part of the SEO's job description going forward.

So "semantic search" is the new way that search engines are ranking pages for queies and "semantic SEO" is how to optimize sites for semantic search.